# Netsuite Formula Calcs

Tags: oracle, netsuite

So I was able to create a search that shows historical unit rates at an item level then I can filter by customer to show any price increases that may have taken place to create a price tracker. It works as advertised. Below is a screen shot of what the output is. "Base Price" is the minimum item rate for lifespan since we transitioned to NetSuite. Then 1-6 months back it will pull the item rate and as you can see, around the 3rd month, it increases and shows change.

[Here is how the search looks when executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJnD8.png)

What I am attempting to do now subtract the values from the formula from the "base price" because that is at the end of the day the total impact value. Eventually I want to bring in quantity so we can see the total impact of these changes to track if we are seeing an increase or not.

EX. If base is $2 and we sell 20 a month. $40 in sales. Now we up it to $3, sales would be $60. But we want to show the $20 in increase impact instead.

Below is from the results tab to generate the above.

[Here is the view from the Results Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKBhw.png)

Is there a way to create that calculation somehow in NS? I am almost thinking it is because I used the DECODE instead of the CASE WHEN ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can generally combine supported functions; you just need to make sure that any functions applied in the Summary or Function columns are replicated in the formula.  For example, your first column "Item Rate" has a Summary function or "Minimum" applied - this needs to be included in the  formula, something like:

```
DECODE(...) - MIN({rate})
```